# Creating rows in dojo

Tags: dojo

I want to display the table in dojo. This table would have multiple rows, each row will have three columns. The cell will be having the text box for populating the data. How to achieve this functionality using the DOJO?

Answer (score 0):

dojo.create("TR",{
 style:"whatever"
},myTBodyNode);